# Weird autocorrect issue on macOS Sierra (period, right-parenthesis, space, space)

Tags: macos, autocorrect

System-wide, when I type:

```
.)
```

My mac replaces this with:

```
.) .
```

or

```
.).
```

I'm thinking that I must have set some weird autocorrect somewhere?  How do I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have "Text Substitution" set up? http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/23/set-up-text-substitution-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Hmm, mine looks like this as the default setting: http://i.imgur.com/FZSukJJ.png . Interestingly, if I type "omw" it does't change this to "On my way!" -- Note, the "." between my link and the word "Interestingly" on this comment was automatically added by the system.  So, I suppose it's double-space related.  Although ".  " doesn't trigger it between sentences.  Weirdness.

Comment: Er, wait a second "Add period with double space" (!) Why is that a default option??  Fixed...

Comment: @arby glad it worked out!

Comment: Arby, that's a default option because it's popular in iOS.  I didn't even notice it in macOS, but it's certainly a nice shortcut in iOS, allowing you to end a sentence with 2 easy "space" characters.